# Doing predictions on Test data in SAS

Tags: sas

I am doing multiple linear regression using SAS. I have divided the data into train and test in the ratio 70 % and 30 %. I have used `proc reg` to build model on the training data. I want to use this model to get predicted values on the test data. How would I do that ?

Comment: Use proc score - see the documentation for an example. A quick and dirty way -> keep data in train data but remove y/dependent variable and use the output predicted variable. You can store the actual y/predicted variable in another variable temporarily.

Comment: Thanks... got it to work